# Convert large file to base64 with Delphi

Tags: delphi, base64, string-conversion

I need to convert a file from 480mb to base64, but I can not. I always get out of memory message. Would anyone have any suggestions?

```
function TFormService.LoadFileToBase64(const AFileName: string): String;
var
//  stream: TMemoryStream;
  Encoder: TIdEncoderMIME;
  Base64String: String;
  LStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Encoder := TIdEncoderMIME.Create;
  LStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    LStream.LoadFromFile(AFileName);
    Base64String := Encoder.Encode(LStream);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Encoder);
    FreeAndNil(LStream);
  end; // try finally


//  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
//  try
//    stream.LoadFromFile(AFilename);
//    result := EncodeBase64(stream.Memory, stream.Size);
//  finally
//    stream.Free;
//  end;
end;
```

Comment: Use TFilestream instead of TMemorystream...

Comment: ty, but did not solve. [link] https://paste.ofcode.org/HTkqhJyu8bUPb4ESU8VEH7 [/link]

Comment: try LStream.Position := 0; after LoadFromFile.

Comment: same problem. out of memory

Comment: How large is the result base64 string? i think string type have a limit of characters.

Comment: It is a pdf file of 430mb

Comment: Have a look at the comment in `TIdEncoder3to4.Encode` and you see why it is happening: "  // No no - this will read the whole thing into memory and what if its MBs?
  // need to load it in smaller buffered chunks MaxInt is WAY too big...."

Comment: yeah, `TIdEncoder3To4` and `TIdDecoder4To3` aren't very good about memory usage when processing large streams. That is a todo item that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @William the resulting base64 string would be 573MB in D2007 and earlier, and 1GB in D2009 and later. Strings are limited to MaxInt (~2 billion) max characters, or available memory, whichever is smaller. But also keep in mind that the data is encoded to an intermediate byte array first, so there is another 573MB in use while preparing the final string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not hold the whole Base64 string in memory. 480 MB encoded to Base64 will result in about 640 M chars, which occupy about 1.28 GB memory. This is bound to fail in a 32 bit application.

Better write the encoded string to a file and use a proper encoder for that. Recent Delphi versions have *System.NetEncoding* for that:

```
procedure ConvertFileToBase64(const AInFileName, AOutFileName: string);
var
  inStream: TStream;
  outStream: TStream;
begin
  inStream := TFileStream.Create(AInFileName, fmOpenRead);
  try
    outStream := TFileStream.Create(AOutFileName, fmCreate);
    try
      TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(inStream, outStream);
    finally
      outStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    inStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Will the output text use ASCII chars, not UTF-16 encoding?

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, plain ASCII. The encoding only works on bytes, so no strings involved here.